# How can I generate mock data object for retrofit response automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, retrofit

I am newbie to writing a test code as an Android developer.
I am using the Kotlin and Retrofit in my android app.

I have a retrofit interface like below:

```
@GET("/3/movie/{movieId}")
fun getMovie(@Query("api_key") apiKey: String, @Path("movieId") movieId: String): Single<TmdbMovieResp>
```

The response is "TmdbMovieResp".

And my test code is :

```
`when`(mockApi.getMovie(mockApiKey, "id")).thenReturn(Single.just(mockMovieResp))
```

This means I should make the "mockMovieResp".
But the "TmdbMovieResp" has too many member variables.
I can make it, but it's too boring!
And in this case it just one test.

If I have more methods and response types, I should do similar task again and again!

Is there any cool solution?

Comment: There is no way that I know of, let see if others know any

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Mockito, use MockK for your mocking, then utilize [relaxed mocks](https://mockk.io/#relaxed-mock).

```
class MyClass {
  fun foo() : ComplexObject { ... }
}

@Test
fun `test foo`() {
  val myClass = spyk(MyClass())
  val complex : ComplexObject = mockk(relaxed = true)

  every { myClass.foo() } returns complex

  assertEquals(complex, myClass.foo())

  println(complex.someIntProperty) // prints 1
}
```

Relaxed mockks return canned data for any value or function, so that you don't need to specify all of those individual properties when they don't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is different approach. You can use https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock

More info by the link. Usage is very simple:

```
    RESTMockServer.whenGET(pathContains("x/y/z/"))
            .thenReturnString("your-response-json");
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do by using your Model classes in your Test method.
As you are using Retrofit you must have some converter like Moshi, GSON for response handling. If you have model classes then use those class for response mocking like below.

```
val success = TmdbMovieResp() //Response Model class
```

Then mock the rest api call with the success result like below.

```
`when`(mockApi.getMovie(mockApiKey, "id")).thenReturn(Single.just(success))
```